# JOGL : forced to sleep in display function to avoid PC crash : Hardware problem or not?

Tags: java, performance, graphics, crash, jogl

i'm a new `JOGL` user and i'm trying to implement some functions with for a future game.

My `GLEventListener` display function just call a function for each entity with the same `GL2` instance as argument.

Currently i'm trying to render animated entities with textures.
So i had loaded `TextureData` ( via `TextureIO` ) in the constructor and i'm just building Texture ( via TextureIO and textureData ) and render it with the classic `gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUAD) --- gl.glEnd()`.

But with two entities like this my PC become totally bugged : it look to work but every graphics are definitely freeze, and i need to manually reboot.

So i've tried to slow down the display function by making the thread sleep. And surprise no more crash.
BUT : with 1 render every 30ms it still crash and with 200ms it do not.

It look to work for my PC, but what if another PC can handle a 20ms refresh ?

.

It clearly look to not be the best way to do.

If my pc cannot go so fast, the app should be "late" and my PC shouldn't bug like that right ?

Does the problem come from `JOGL` configuration / initialization ? Or it just come from my hardware ( `i915 graphic card :/` ) ?

And wherever he comes, what is the best way to handle it ?

I've look a lot at google, but i didn't find a similar topic, so i'm directly asking to you :)

Thx.

Comment: I advise you to ask your question on the official Jogamp forum but I think that you would have the same problem if you used OpenGL in C. It might come from your driver or maybe your hardware is going to die. Try to enable vertical synchronization and provide a SSCCE. By the way, Google search isn't the panacea.

Comment: Ty for your answer gouessej. Indeed my hardware isn't so performant, but i've just solved the problem today. To avoid some rotation / translation / color stuff from an entity rendering to another one, i was using pushMatrix and popMatrix before and after every render function in the display loop + my texture were built with a TextureData in the display loop for the glContext, i read that the default texture id(0) could replace the matrix's pushing/poping and now textures are load with a glContext in a init function, not in display loop + i've watch some more code example for gl Init. Solved :)

Comment: Next time, post a SSCCE: http://sscce.org Your explanations weren't accurate enough to get a valuable answer. Yes, it's an excellent idea to create each unique texture only once and you should do the same for other resources, VBOs, ... If you had posted your source code, it would have been easier to help you. Your original post didn't mention that you recreated your texture at each call of GLEventListener.display() which was obviously a very bad practice. Use either glGenTextures() or the texture ID stored into com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.texture.Texture.getTextureObject().

Comment: Do you call Texture.bind(GL) or GL.glBindTexture()? You shouldn't need to manipulate the texture ID if you built the Texture object from the TextureData object.